# Uploading User Made Videos to iPhone (from Vista)

Tags: windows-vista, video, iphone, file-transfer, camera

Once a user downloads a video created with the iPhone 3GS and then deletes it from the iPhone, that video cannot be uploaded back to the iPhone...according to Apple.

The videos are not treated as Photos and are not allowed to sync to and from the iPhone freely.  Has anyone discovered a program or tweek that allows one to upload video to the iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have not owned a 3gs yet (still on 3g), but can't you download the movies to the computer, import them into iTunes, and then sync the video back to the iPod video portion of the iPhone?

Edit: I originally stated iPhoto, but OP wants vista options. Changed.

Comment: Nearsightedly, I failed to disclose that I'm using a PC with Vista.  If I were using an Apple, however, I imagine that I would still want the videos to appear in the "photos" section of the phone rather that in the iPod.

Comment: @Darren E.: Oops, good point, you did mention vista. Edited.

Comment: @Darren E.: Just curious, does the iPod video portion not work for you, or do you just prefer the photos section?

Comment: I can get video in the iPod, but they have to be videos that iTunes would designate for the iPod.  When you produce a video on the iPhone 3GS using the onboard camera and then move it to your PC, you can't get it back to the iPhone.  And as far as I know, there is no way to prompt iTunes to accept it into the iPod (or anyplace for that matter.  Page 106: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPhone_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: I'll try the importing and let you know what I get.

Comment: Okay, the importing works.  But, again, the videos are segregated from photos.  Just as on the iPhone 3G, you have a "Photos" icon and and iPod icon.  There is no movie icon.  As you produced a video with the phone it will be stored in the Camera Roll.  However, if you wish to keep it there it will download to your PC if your PC settings are such that you automatically download photos to your PC.  That's pretty disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to jailbreak and copy (SFTP and such) the video onto your phone.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DA2tGJr-rGo

Comment: Thank you for this comment.  My phone is not jailbroken and it'll stay that way because of all the legitimate features I use.

Comment: It just seems like there would be a work-around for getting this data back on to the phone.